# CSS: Need boxes at 62% and 38%, but can't seem to find the right formula or code

Tags: css, width, box

Trying to get the left box at 62% of the width to the left and the right box at 38%.  Where ever I add the percentages, they still sit at 50%.  Any ideas?  Thank you for any help/advice you can share.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#sides {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  background-color: white;
}

.sideleft {
  flex: 1;    
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.sideright {
  flex: 1;    
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

#left {
  background-color: #333333;
}

#right {
  background-color: #018DCA;
}

h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

h2 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="sides">
  <div class="sideleft" id="left" align="right">
    <h1>text</h1>
    <h2>text</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="sideright" id="right">
    <h1>text</h1>
    <h2>text</h2>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/maio/ue8wgnkx/

Answer (score 1):

[flex property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) is the combination of `flex-grow: flex-shrink: flex-basis:` ,

so to set width you need to set `flex-basis:`

for ex.: `flex: 0 1 38%;`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/ue8wgnkx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make the left and right side, float left and have display:inline-block here is the css with it working. You also have to set your container div in this case sides to 100%

```
#sides {
  display: flex;
    width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
    margin: 0px;
}

.sideleft {
  flex: 1;  
     width: 62%;
  margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.sideright {
  flex: 1;    
    width: 38%;
  margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#sides {

  padding: 0px 0px;
  background-color: white;
}

.sideleft {
  flex: 1;    
  padding: 00px;
  margin: 0;
}

.sideright {
  flex: 1;    
  padding: 00px;


}

#left {
  background-color: #333333;
}

#right {
  background-color: #018DCA;
}

h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

h2 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="sides">
  <div class="sideleft" id="left"  style=" width:62%">
    <h1>text</h1>
    <h2>text</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="sideright" id="right" style=" width:38%; margin-left:62%">
    <h1>text</h1>
    <h2>text</h2>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

css width box